# Getting display:table's border on top of display:table-cell's border?

Tags: html, css, border

When using `display:table` and `display:table-cell`, the `border` of the `table-cell` elements appear on top of the `table`. How can I make sure the parent `table`'s border is on top?

I have a simple HTML layout:

```
<div class="section-header">General Properties</div>
<div id="policy-parameters">
  <div class="parameter-row">
    <label for="inputPolicyName" class="">Name</label>
    <div class="parameter-entry">
      <input type="text" class="" id="inputPolicyName">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="parameter-row">
    <label for="inputPolicyDescription" class="">Description</label>
    <div class="parameter-entry">
      <input type="text" class="" id="inputPolicyDescription">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Combined with a straight forward CSS:

```
#policy-parameters {
  border: 1px solid #6c6c6c;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  display: table;
  width: 100%; }
  #policy-parameters .parameter-row {
    display: table-row; }
    #policy-parameters .parameter-row:not(:last-child) {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #c4c2be; }
    #policy-parameters .parameter-row label {
      background-color: #deddd9;
      border-right: 1px solid #c4c2be;
      display: table-cell;
      padding: 5px 3px 5px 7px;
      width: 175px; }
    #policy-parameters .parameter-row .parameter-entry {
      background-color: #f7f6f5;
      display: table-cell;
      padding: 5px; }
      #policy-parameters .parameter-row .parameter-entry input[type="text"] {
        width: 400px; }
```

But when the table displays, I get the following result:

[image]

How can I make sure make sure the `table`'s `border` appears on top of the `table-cell`'s `border`?

UPDATE:

JSFiddle of the effect: http://jsfiddle.net/EvilClosetMonkey/8N7w2/

Note that the same effect is happening on the vertical `label`'s `border-right` too.

Comment: Question updated with JSFiddle.

Comment: a simple workaround would be to set the table border to 2px instead of 1px, its not much of a difference but it will put the table border over the cell's border

Comment: @Filly, this fixes the `border` issue but it creates a `background-color` (actually a `width`) issue. See what happens after the text fields here: http://jsfiddle.net/EvilClosetMonkey/8N7w2/1/. Also, shouldn't `display:table-row` and `display:table-cell` only appear within a `display:table` for proper CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to remove `border: collapse` and apply the border only to the table-cell elements and not the table row.  Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8N7w2/4/

```
#policy-parameters {
  border: 1px solid #6c6c6c;
  /* removed border-collapse: collapse; */
  display: table;
  width: 100%; 
}

#policy-parameters .parameter-row {
    display: table-row; 
}

#policy-parameters .parameter-row label {
      background-color: #deddd9;
      border-right: 1px solid #c4c2be;
      display: table-cell;
      padding: 5px 3px 5px 7px;
      width: 175px; }

#policy-parameters .parameter-row .parameter-entry {
      background-color: #f7f6f5;
      display: table-cell;
      padding: 5px; 
}
#policy-parameters .parameter-row .parameter-entry input[type="text"] {
        width: 400px; 
}

/* added `> *` to apply border to elements within row, not row itself */
#policy-parameters .parameter-row:not(:last-child) > * {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #c4c2be; 
}
```

Comment: I had read elsewhere `border:collapse` was needed, and saw results that implied I needed it. Adding the `> *` to the row seemed to elevate that need, and keeps things clean! Like it!

Comment: `border-collapse` is useful when border is placed around all table cells.  In your case you are applying borders selectively and there is no need to collapse them.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because of

```
border-collapse: collapse;
```

collapse - in which both the space and the borders between table cells collapse so there is only one border and no space between cells.

[Here is the demo](http://codepen.io/4dgaurav/pen/BaAsF) to show that in which I applied the border fully (not bottom) on `.parameter-row` and it overlayed the table border as there can be only one border and no space in between.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you don't want the cell border to overlap the table border, so we try mimicking the table-border using `box-shadow`, that way the fake table-border does not cover the cell border but the cell border also does not cover it:

```
#policy-parameters {  
 border-collapse: collapse;
 display: table;
 width: 100%; 
 /* the fake border */
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #6c6c6c;  
 margin:1px;
}
```

### [Updated demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/8N7w2/3/)